# Angular 2: Not able to detect changes in child component

Tags: angular

I have created a component as `<app-delete></app-delete>`. And I am trying to re use this component in child component. Look at code shown below that will show the exact place where I am calling.

I have a component as `<app-profile></app-profile>`. In this component I have child component `<app-delete-user></app-delete-user>`. Inside app-delete-user component I am trying to use app-delete component.

My app delete component looks like as shown below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._zone.run(() => {
        window['delete'] = () => {
          this.title = 'hi'
          this._ref.detectChanges();
        };
    });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
Title is: {{title}}
```

Here I am getting output as 'Title is:'.
I tried calling change detection manually but no success. I am guessing issue is with calling it in child component. Please let me know possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

I see enough information here.  How are you passing the value from parent to child (or are you?).  If you pass an object the change should be reflected within the object.  If you're trying to reassign the object, I don't believe the parent dereferences it.

Comment: I am not passing any value from parent to child. I have a title defined in AppDelete component whose value is not getting updated.